# Basis of a linear space need not contain a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I've encountered the following problem and I cannot think of anything that disproves it:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional linear space, and let $S$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove a basis for $V$ need not contain a basis for $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S = \{(x, y) \in V : y = x \}$. Let the basis for $V$ be $\{ (1,0), (0, 1) \}$. No subset of this is a basis of the line.

Comment: Why would $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ itself not be a basis for $S$?

Comment: @Oracular Neither of these vectors is in S, so they can't be basis vectors for S.